# How can I "delay" in Zsh with a float-point number?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, sleep

In Zsh there is a `wait` (for a process or job) command, a `while` (Seconds == Delay) command, and a `sched` (Do later if shell still running) command, but no "delay" command.  If there were, I fear it would be limited to whole second delays.  I need a "delay" statement that can essentially cause the procedure/task to do almost nothing for the time specified in a fixed point number or until an certain clock time.

Most scripts would use "sleep", but I would like to have the delay timer run without having to open the IO; I am seeking the ideal that nearly anything can be accomplished from within Zsh.

Does anyone know how to perhaps make a function (or maybe builtin/module) perform a floating point idle delay in seconds?

Comment: To be completely picky, in Ada you delay for a Duration (or until a Time). Neither of which is a floating point number; Duration is fixed-point.

Comment: Is this a question or an essay?

Comment: This question would be improved by removing about 80-90% of it. The virtues of Ada and Zsh are not relevant to your question, which is really quite simple: *Is it possible to sleep for fractional seconds in zsh?*

Comment: If you like, I can shorten my question by removing statements that are not strictly necessary... Done.  Question, not essay; I have a tendency  to be very wordy.

Comment: I have no desire to fight others who have taken the liberty to edit out of the question what they don't fully understand, but I wish to make it known that that is the reason the question's wording no longer makes sense.  In this network, popular opinion counts a little more than openness, truth, and common ideals.  For all who dare learn this trick to Zsh, I wish you find many more gems in Zsh, and suggest you follow the bread crumbs to Ada from which the question was inspired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that as long as the I/O is confined to built-ins, the I/O doesn't create a noticeable lag and doesn't depend on anything outside of Zsh. With helpful input from grochmal and a number of experiments I have come up with a simple looped file descriptor for the `read` built-in command with the `:` (null) built-in command:

```
: $(read -u 1 -t 10)
```

The standard out of the read command is connected to Zsh for expansion as an argument to `:` (null), so it is guaranteed to receive no input.  Knowing that it will never receive input, we have the `read` command listen to the standard out with `-u 1`.  The timeout option of Zsh `read` accepts floating point numbers; It should be consistent on any system that runs Zsh.  Finally, even if shell option ERREXIT is on the `read` timeout-failure status should not be a problem, because `read` is actually running in a sub-shell, destined to end anyway, and `:` always returns true.  If ERRRETURN option is on, I don't know that behavior yet, but the fix would be to add `||:` to the end of the `read` command.

Now it is possible to create a function or alias-to-anonymous-function that interprets any manner of argument or input to reliably create a delay in a floating point number of seconds:

```
# function sleep {    -- optional switch-out for the system command
#                        after POSIX & GNU compatibility verified.
function delay {
   emulate -LR zsh -o extendedglob -o nullglob
   local Delay=1.
   if [[ $1 == (#b)([[:digit:]](#c1,).(#c0,1)[[:digit:]](#c0,))(s|m|h|d|w|) ]]
   then
      if [[ $match[2] == (s|) ]] Delay=$match[1]
      if [[ $match[2] == (m) ]] Delay=$[ $match[1] * 60. ** 1 ]
      if [[ $match[2] == (h) ]] Delay=$[ $match[1] * 60. ** 2 ]
      if [[ $match[2] == (d) ]] Delay=$[ ($match[1] * 60. ** 2) * 24 ]
      if [[ $match[2] == (w) ]] Delay=$[ (($match[1] * 60. ** 2) * 24) * 7 ]
      : $(read -u 1 -t $Delay)
   else
      print -u 2 "Invalid delay time: $1"
      return 1
   fi
}
```

Comment: That's good stuff +1.  Notably the part `(s|m|h|d|w|)`, it allows for `delay 3` to be treated like `delay 3s`, therefore it would be familiar for people using sleep.

Answer (score 5):

I'll argue that you are making the wrong assumption.  `zsh` is a shell, and therefore its purpose is to be a shell.  One important point in being a shell is to be a POSIX compatible shell.  Moreover since `zsh` is fully backward compatible with `bash`, which in turn is fully backward compatible with the bourne shell that should be a POISX shell.

That means that `zsh` must have access to `sleep` since [`sleep` is required for a POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html).

And that is as far as we go with the POSIX compatibility argument.  Now for a practical use argument.  Most systems will use [GNU coreutils `sleep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sleep-invocation.html#sleep-invocation) to implement `sleep` which allow for floating point arguments.  Therefore the following is POSIX portable:

```
if ! sleep 0.03; then
    sleep 1
fi
```

And should work as a fine grained delay in most cases, whilst still not break in the rare cases the OS does not use GNU coreutils.  As far as I am aware these rare cases are just AIX and HP-UX systems.

Comment: @MicahW `/dev/zero` may not exist on some systems, MinGW comes to mind.  I'd go with something like `read -t 0.03 /does-not-exist`, but then someone may actually create `/does-not-exist` and you are screwed.  A lot depends on what you want to sacrifice: speed or portability.  You just can't have both with shell programming.

Comment: Thankyou. The problem is that I have written very useful scripts using sleep, but their timing behavior is unpredictable and insufficient because of the system calls to an outside process.  In my opinion, sleep should have always been a builtin. I am trying to make a workaround. The closest I have come is (EDITED for @grochmal) `: $(read -u 1 -s -t 10)`. It seems to use zero cpu time, accepts floating point numbers, and does not depend on zero...

Comment: @MicahW - Yep, `-u 1` does the trick.  But I have the impression you are falling into a [premature optimisation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), and we all heard the *premature optimization is the root of all evil*, at some point.  As another example: If I had to sleep 3 microsecond I know that I will need to do it in C.  That is because I will need to call the kernel scheduler.  No matter what I would do in, say, python, I would never achieve 3 microseconds.

Comment: You may be right.  I am very detail-oriented, though a bit playful in personality, so it is entirely possible that I try to fix a specific problem before I know that I really need to.  Even so, I have created interactive scripts that run other programs where unreliable delays can at least be very annoying.  My big goal is to centralize work to Zsh for cross-platform support and a more fully functional emergency environment.  Optimizations can be great, but I often get by without them.